# Cycles not Showing Textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine

My textures are not showing specifically when rendered and in cycles.

- If I use the material preview mode, everything is fine;
- If I render in Evee, fine as well;
- If I render (preview or output) in cycles, the texture is not used to generate the image.

This must be some setting that I changed by accident because the cycles render was fine yesterday and I have outputs from this object with the Cycles working fine.
Could someone help me with this? I've already tried tweaking some settings and searching here for the answer but nothing worked...

[image]

Cycles and Render Preview:
[image: Cycles and Render Preview]

Evee and Render Preview:
[image: Evee and Render Preview]

Cycles and Material Preview:
[image: Cycles and Material Preview]

Comment: hello, please pack the imagse, save and share your file again

Comment: I believe they are packed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the *Texture Coordinate From Instancer* option, it is made for particles to inherit the material of the emitter.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!